# Java or Ubuntu Bug? (Problem with Minecraft)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, java, minecraft

As a lefty I wanted to change my Minecraft keybindings for walking to p, l, ö, ä so that I have the mouse in the left hand. Then I realized a bug: If I press ö or ä to walk to the right or backwards I just don't stop walking when I have stopped pressing the button. I figured out this does not happen on Windows 10 so it has to be a Ubuntu or at least Linux thing. After some testing I figured out that these are not the only buttons that have this problem, all these have this problem: ö, ä, ü, #, +. I am not quite sure if this is a Java or an Ubuntu bug. What do you think? Do you have any idea how to find out the issue or how to fix it?

- keyboard: Razer Blackwiddow Chroma, German version
- German keyboard configuration on Ubuntu (and also Windows where I tested if this is a bug concerning Minecraft)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Xeon E3 1231v3
- Gtx 1060 from Palit
- OpenJDK 1.8
- Minecraft Version 1.12 if that matters

Feel free to ask me if you need some more information.

Comment: Im not 100% sure if linux kernel handles razer keyboards I think they dont use that and replace that driver for a generic one have you cheked out the system keyboard layout?

Comment: What do you mean with handle? I can use the keyboard without any problems ussually and all hardwarebuttons work. The chroma configuration does not work quite well, it just has the pulse effect. But I use a driver for the lightning called the polychromatic controller if that counts.

Comment: ok I have asked someone if he can try out reproduce this issue and he has the same problems like me. But he told me that the problem might be the libraries specific for linux machines.

Comment: oh wait I know why you are encountering this issue, you are using openJDK

Comment: Is there a difference between the openjdk and oracles? And can I fix the issue by using oracles?

Comment: See the links i provided to you

Comment: Ok thank you! I cannot try it out today anymore but I will do this tomorrow! I am very glad if this works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that openJDK is not working properly, because that GNU folks make reverse engineering for releasing code, it may not work as espected [specially](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL_(Legacy)) with the newest versions thus in the Minecraft page is [told](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/) that you must use [Java official packages](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#install) for running minecraft properly.

so the easiest way to install java in ubuntu, is opening  terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> 
and type this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

since you have openJDK1.8 already installed you may want to remove it

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk --auto-remove
```

or just make the original Java as default

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

hope this helps

Comment: Ok I have tried it today and I am afraid I have to tell you this didn't work out. I have checked if it uses the correct Java Version, but it did not work.

Comment: @Booming that's because your system is still using the old configuration, delete the `.minecraft` folder in your `/home/user/~` directory