# Minecraft native install fails, cant find lib

Tags: libraries, minecraft

I am trying to install Minecraft via the native launcher on Ubuntu. I tried:

`wget https://launcher.mojang.com/mc-staging/download/Minecraft_staging.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i Minecraft_staging.deb`

`sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh`

and ran into: `error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

After some Googling it seems like I should install some sort of libicui dependency, but every one I tried didn't work. Any ideas?

Trying to install Java:

```
king@king-MS-7640 ~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libicu-dev : Depends: libicu55 (= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is to be installed
 libicu55 : Breaks: libicu55:i386 (!= 55.1-7) but 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 libicu55:i386 : Breaks: libicu55 (!= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is to be installed
 oracle-java8-set-default : PreDepends: oracle-java8-installer but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
king@king-MS-7640 ~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libicu55
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libicu55
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,659 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 294474 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libicu55:amd64 (55.1-7ubuntu0.2) over (55.1-7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libicu55/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libicu55:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: first able, have you installed java? if not please read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/931293/java-or-ubuntu-bug-problem-with-minecraft/931622#931622

Comment: @RenatoA. thanks for the tip- I tried installing java from your instructions in the post you linked but ran into the error above

Comment: can you play minecraft? reboot and try again

Comment: Nope, same error as before :(