# Can No longer Right-Click and Run MC.Jar (Minecraft) with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, minecraft, jar

Double-Click just opens it as a archive.

So what is the solution to run a Jar file under Ubuntu 17.10. If I right-click and select find application, Java 8 does not show up?

```
&>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-8u144-b01-2-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I did find this (http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/04/install-minecraft-ubuntu-16-04-ubuntu-16-10/) (Is this safe?)

Comment: you want the solution? don't use **openjdk** use the standard java
please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/931293/java-or-ubuntu-bug-problem-with-minecraft/931622#931622 for a tutorial

Comment: Yes, Very Nice! Now the right-click option is there!

Comment: omg that admin answer(how the heck they reach 23.3k golden points?)... now you cant delete this post for that.... do you want me to post the answer explaining briefly what happened? because im lazy man

Comment: Nahh, your comment is good!

Answer (score 1):

From your username, I'm going to assume you're trying to run a dedicated server, and will post my answer as such. This system has been battle-tested and is currently being used by a network where I am the infrastructure admin (alongside other fancy features), as well as countless other entry-level servers and production networks.

If you want a persistent auto-restarting server, you might look at [creating a `systemd` service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Using_units) for your server. You will lose your GUI and headless interface, but you'll still be able to issue commands to your server through [RCON](http://wiki.vg/RCON) or similar.

Effectively, you'd need to create a new user (let's call it `mcserver`) that will handle your server tasks:

```
sudo adduser --system --disabled-login --group --home /opt/mcserver
```

Next, you'll want to switch to this user:

```
sudo -u mcserver
cd /opt/mcserver
```

While you're here, copy all of your game server files and whatever over.

Next, create a new script to launch your server. Do *not* include any relaunch logic or similar. It should be very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -Xms1024M -Xmx4G -jar -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar minecraft.jar --nojline --noconsole
```

Mark the file as executable using `chmod +x mcserver.sh`.

You can `exit` the session for `mcserver`, you won't need it anymore.

Create a new file (`mcserver.service`) in `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mcserver.sh
```

In this file, add the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Vanilla Minecraft Server

Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mcserver
Group=mcserver

ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateTmp=true
InaccessibleDirectories=/root /sys /srv -/opt /media -/lost+found
ReadWriteDirectories=/var/minecraft/server
WorkingDirectory=/var/minecraft/server    

Restart=on-failure
RestartSecs=5

ExecStart=/opt/mcserver/mcserver.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once you're done, you'll need to activate the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable mcserver.service
sudo systemctl start mcserver.service
```

The server will now auto-start on system boot, and run normally.

Note that the server will auto-restart on a failure (non-zero exit code), so `/stop` will stop the server without the chance for a respawn. While you may also stop the server with `systemctl stop mcserver.service`, it'll be unsafe as the server will not get to gracefully die. You can, however, use `rcon` to have the aforementioned command send a graceful stop. This, however, will be left as an exercise to the reader.

Backup scrips can still be run, though it would be advisable to use a [user cron-entry](https://superuser.com/a/170873/317805) that ZIPs the entire folder, and stores it somewhere safe.

Comment: This post was about running the Minecraft Game Jar. In 16.10 you could right-click and open with Java but in 17.10 that option has been removed. Very Impressive post though!

Comment: @Renato A. had the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I think this is a good tutorial for marking a mc server. kudos for you admin

Answer (score 0):

I did make a script like running my server but there must be a better way. Also, not very elegant, just typing java -jar MC.jar in terminal, both ways leave an open terminal.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms1024M -Xmx4G -jar -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar MC.jar
echo "If you want to completely stop the server process now, press 
Ctrl+C before the time is up!"
echo "Rebooting in:"
for i in 5 4 3 2 1
do
echo "$i..."
sleep 1
done
echo "Rebooting now!"
done
```